# How to make generic arraylist parcelable in Android?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have such a Class: (full definition can be found [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/Models/AList.java))

```
public class AList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

It is a C#-like generic list.

How should I implement `AList` as a `Parcelable`? I have found examples online but their data types are determined. How should I deal with generic types?

This is my current try:

```
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(list);
}

protected AList(Parcel in) {
    list = in.readArrayList(null);
}

public static final Creator<AList> CREATOR = new Creator<AList>() {
    @Override
    public AList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new AList(in);
    }

    @Override
    public AList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new AList[size];
    }
};
```

but the constructor would give me `BadParcelableException`.

I have also tried this:

```
protected AList(Parcel in) {
    in.readList(list, T.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

but `T` cannot be used as a variable so I don't know how to fix this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up implementing `AList` as a `Parcelable`. However, since `AList` is `ArrayList`-like, I can treat it exactly as an `ArrayList` when I need to write `AList<T>` to Parcel.

For example, I have a `AList<Tag> Tags` declared in `Food` class. So in `protected Food(Parcel in)`, I can write:

```
    ArrayList<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    in.readTypedList(tags, Tag.CREATOR);
    Tags = new AList<>(tags);
```

Of course, I have implemented `Tag` as a `Parcelable`. And I can have such `writeToParcel`:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(Name);
    dest.writeString(ImagePath);
    dest.writeTypedList(Tags.ToArrayList());
    dest.writeString(Note);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (IsFavorite ? 1 : 0));
    if (DateAdded == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeLong(DateAdded);
    }
}
```

My source code for `Food` class is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/Models/Food.java).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class  Sample<T> implements Parcelable {
ArrayList<T> list;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(this.list);
}

public Sample() {
}

protected Sample(Parcel in) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
    in.readList(this.list, T.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Sample> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Sample>() {
    @Override
    public Sample createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Sample(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Sample[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Sample[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: `T.class.getClassLoader()` will not compile as explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `List` to be parcelable, each element of that `List` should implement `Parcelable`. So basically you would define your List as `ArrayList<Parcelable> list = new ArrayList<>()`

```
SomeClass implements Parcelable {
...
}
```

A couple of tests:

```
list.add("test"); // error, String doesn't implement Parcelable
list.add(new SomeClass()); // fine
list.add(new android.location.Address(Locale.getDefault())); // fine
```

This is commonly used to attach data to `Intent`s, example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class)
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", list);
```